# Why is this trained model misclassifying new cases?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning, theano

Below is text / code from [a recent SO post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692653/problems-with-theano-convnet-model-accuracy-in-wild-data) that I hope you could comment on:

Using Keras/Theano, I successfully trained a model using the [Keras sample code for CIFAR10](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py). It ran for about 2 hours on a MacPro with a GTX98-Ti GPU, with Theano (latest version) backend.

All original parameters are unchanged and model reached ~81% accuracy. At the end of script the weights (weights.h5, 5MB on disk) and architecture (arch.json) were exported.

In another script I restored the model and weights, and tried to classify single images using:

```
from skimage.data import imread
import os
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = model_from_json(open('./arch.json').read())
model.load_weights('./weights.h5')
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./input/singles/'):
    for idx, file in enumerate(files):
        if not file.startswith('.'):
            file_path = root + os.sep + file
            img = imread(file_path)
            img = fn_resize(img, 32) # this is a resize function in another file
                                     # I have plotted images at this point and they are
                                     # correctly sized smaller version of the original
                                     # normalized between 0-1 as in training

            img = img.reshape((1, 3, 32, 32))

            y_pred = int(model.predict_classes(img, 1))
            pred_labels = ['airplane', 'automobile', ' bird', 'cat', 'deer',
                           'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
            print(pred_labels[y_pred], "prediction \\\", file, "truth")
```

Essentially it restores the model and architecture, then loops through 10 images from the Net in a folder, resizing them to 32x32 pixels, reshaping the array, and forwarding the data to `model.predict_classes()`.

I was surprised to see the below output, in which none of the images was classified correctly. **Has anyone done such an experiment and knows if there are issues with the model build or if my procedure is incorrect?**

```
Using Theano backend.
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 980 Ti (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN 5005)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
truck predicted \\\ airplane.jpeg truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
airplane predicted \\\ bird.jpeg truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
airplane predicted \\\ car.jpg truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
airplane predicted \\\ cat.jpeg truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
frog predicted \\\ deer.jpeg truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
ship predicted \\\ frog.jpeg truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
automobile predicted \\\ horse.jpeg truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
automobile predicted \\\ dog.tif truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
frog predicted \\\ ship.jpeg truth
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
airplane predicted \\\ truck.jpeg truth

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You're looping over 10 images here, and could loop over 1. Is your question really how to do that? or why they're not classified correctly? because classifying 1 image is something you've already done.

Comment: yes @sean, I have looped over 1 image as well and the result is the same: misclassification, when one would expect something closer to correct classification, given the model accuracy is ~81%. Ten images here is to prove this isn't a fluke. My question is not about how to loop N images, it is about the correct procedure to input a single image against a classifier, if others have experience with this, and why the unexpected results. Thanks for pitching in!

Comment: I think the unanswered posts are not relevant here. You have a bug/fault in your logic either in the predictor or the training code export or in how they match up. At the top level your attempted approach looks sound. The other posts presumably also have a bug or fault, and the reason they are unanswered is that the problem is not explainable other than debugging the implementation in detail - answers to those other posts would not help you, and it is likely to be hard work to pick through the code, have a conversation with OP, find the fault. All to fix one likely-to-be unique problem.

Comment: I have in the past found and fixed bugs in NN implementations posted here or SO, just to get the practice. So I do have some appreciation for how much effort it takes, and how little the end Q&A pair is appreciated by anyone other than the OP (and even that is not guaranteed)

Comment: thanks@NeilSlater, I fully understand what you mean -- it's just interesting that this specific case use is apparently straightforward but not discussed much -- OTH, there's a plethora of tutorials in which a classic dataset (MNIST, CIFAR) is trained and validated against huge test sets  -- I'll keep researching

Comment: @pepe: If you are using a validation set, you can test that you are correctly saving and loading the network across two scripts by loading the data as you are here and continuing the training process. If the training and validation losses shoot up to similar to start of training then the problem is likely with model persistence code.

Comment: I just did that: the losses start where the prior training ended and progressively get smaller in successive sessions with saving and loading. So for example I did a run of 200 epochs and reached 0.7 loss and saved the weights/architecture. Then I loaded both and continued 20 epochs from there: it starts at 0.7 and goes down to ~0.6. I did this successively  and it seems convincing the model save/restore is working.

Comment: OK fix the title maybe? it says this is about "how to test a single input"

Comment: @SeanOwen sure, I changed the title and removed initial commentary as it does not seem to help. Let me know if you'd like additional modifications.

Comment: Looking at the Keras sample code, it uses data augmentation by default. Did you switch on zca whitening or center or normalisation? That would change the pixel feature values . . .

Comment: Go over your whole test set again. You might just have had bad luck with 10 images. - another idea, without looking at your code - is that you forgot preprocessing steps